# Which type declarations do I have to use in Cython for Shapely Objects

Tags: python, cython, shapely

I am new to cython and this might be a beginners question.
I have a piece of python code (just a single function) that gets executed several thousand times during my script. Therefore, speeding it up (even if just slightly) would largely improve runtime of the script.
I tried to do so with Cython. Reading some tutorials, I learned, that a first step would be to add the correct C type declarations to the function. However, since this function uses Shapely objects, I don't know which types to use.

This is the python code:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
from shapely.linear import line_locate_point
from shapely.strtree import STRtree

def xy2sd(traj, centerline):
    '''
    Transforms a set of points into the frenet frame given by centerline
    traj: np.ndarray of shape [N, 2] where N is the number of points in the trajectory
    centerline: np.ndarray of shape [M, 2] where M is the number of points in the centerline
    '''
    line = LineString(centerline)
    s_orig = line_locate_point(line, Point([0, 0]))

    s = np.zeros(traj.shape[0])
    d = np.zeros(traj.shape[0])

    nth_entry = 100
    tree = STRtree([Point(x) for id, x in enumerate(line.coords) if id % nth_entry == 0])

    for i in range(traj.shape[0]):
        pnt = Point(traj[i])
        s[i] = line.line_locate_point(pnt)
        d[i] = pnt.distance(line)

        min_idx = tree.nearest(pnt)*nth_entry

        pnt_min_dist = centerline[min_idx]
        pnt_behind = centerline[min_idx-1]

        sign = (pnt_behind[0]-pnt_min_dist[0])*(pnt.y-pnt_min_dist[1]) - \
            (pnt_behind[1]-pnt_min_dist[1])*(pnt.x-pnt_min_dist[0])
        sign = 1 if sign >= 0 else -1 if sign < 0 else 0

        d[i] = sign*d[i]

    sd_coords = np.zeros(traj.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    sd_coords[:, 0] = s - s_orig
    sd_coords[:, 1] = d

    return sd_coords
```

So far i changed it to the following Cython code

```
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
from shapely.linear import line_locate_point
from shapely.strtree import STRtree

def xy2sd(traj, centerline):
    '''
    Transforms a set of points into the frenet frame given by centerline
    traj: np.ndarray of shape [N, 2] where N is the number of points in the trajectory
    centerline: np.ndarray of shape [M, 2] where M is the number of points in the centerline
    '''
    line = LineString(centerline)
    s_orig = line_locate_point(line, Point([0, 0]))

    cdef np.ndarray s = np.zeros(traj.shape[0])
    cdef np.ndarray d = np.zeros(traj.shape[0])

    cdef int nth_entry = 100
    tree = STRtree([Point(x) for id, x in enumerate(line.coords) if id % nth_entry == 0])

    cdef int i
    cdef int min_idx
    cdef np.ndarray pnt_min_dist
    cdef np.ndarray pnt_behind
    cdef double cross_prod
    cdef int sign
    for i in range(traj.shape[0]):
        pnt = Point(traj[i])
        s[i] = line.line_locate_point(pnt)
        d[i] = pnt.distance(line)

        min_idx = tree.nearest(pnt)*nth_entry

        pnt_min_dist = centerline[min_idx]
        pnt_behind = centerline[min_idx-1]

        cross_prod = (pnt_behind[0]-pnt_min_dist[0])*(pnt.y-pnt_min_dist[1]) - \
            (pnt_behind[1]-pnt_min_dist[1])*(pnt.x-pnt_min_dist[0])
        sign = 1 if cross_prod >= 0 else -1 if cross_prod < 0 else 0

        d[i] = sign*d[i]

    cdef np.ndarray sd_coords = np.zeros(traj.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    sd_coords[:, 0] = s - s_orig
    sd_coords[:, 1] = d

    return sd_coords
```

I am able to compile this code, however i did not notice any speedup.
I suppose, this is due to the lacking type declarations for the shapely objects of `line` `tree` and `pnt`.
Which types do I have to use there? Can I expect major speedups from just adding the types or is there anything else I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) numpy type declarations are usually only useful if you specify the dtype. And even then the give faster indexing of individual elements (which isn't what you're doing here). 2) The shapely types looks to just be Python objects (i.e. there's no suitable type declaration for Cython)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @DavidW. Does that mean, that there is no potential to speed this up using Cython?

Comment: Probably worth typing `s`, `d`, `pnt_min_dist` and `pnt_behind` properly, since you are indexing into those and you probably do know the dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to work out what you would want to do is see how it's done in shapely itself, for example in
[geometry_helpers.pyx](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/blob/main/shapely/_geometry_helpers.pyx)

It would likely look something like this:

```
import shapely

# import the types / functions you need from shapely here
from shapely._geos cimport get_geos_handle, ...
from shapely._pygeos_api cimport import_shapely_c_api, ...

import_shapely_c_api()

# your actual code ...
```

However shapely already uses cython internally on the slow bits, so there might not be many easy wins left.

### Alternative Idea

I think you can make better use of shapely to get a decent speedup without the extra complexity of cython though - some ideas:

- `line.line_locate_point(pnt)` and `pnt.distance(line)` don't seem to have any index so will be pretty slow, would avoid if possible and use a `tree.query` instead
- creating lots of geometry seems very slow (e.g. `[Point(x) for ...]`) ideally batch these up e.g. via `shapely.points(array)`
- tree.nearest(...) can take an array of geometries and seems much faster if done in one go the one-at-a-time.

Putting some of this together I get something like the below which ran about **30x faster** than the original for me, though is not quite identical.

```py
import shapely

def xy2sd_alternate(traj, centerline):
    # RTree of all the line segments in the centerline
    tmp = np.repeat(centerline, repeats=2, axis=0)[1:-1]
    ind = np.arange(tmp.shape[0])//2
    lns = shapely.linestrings(tmp, indices=ind)
    tree = shapely.STRtree(lns)

    # distances along the centerline at each of its points
    dists = np.zeros(centerline.shape[0])
    dists[1:] = ((np.diff(cl, axis=0)**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5).cumsum()

    # get the indexes of the closest centerline line-segment for each trajectory point
    nearest_line_idx = tree.nearest(shapely.points(traj))

    # convert to frenet frame coords
    sd = np.zeros(traj.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(traj.shape[0]):
        idx = nearest_line_idx[i]

        # (bx,by) = normalized vector for the closest line segment
        segment_length = dists[idx+1] - dists[idx]
        bx = (centerline[idx+1, 0] - centerline[idx, 0]) / segment_length
        by = (centerline[idx+1, 1] - centerline[idx, 1]) / segment_length

        # (tx,ty) = vector from start of closest segment to trajectory point
        tx = traj[i,0] - centerline[idx, 0]
        ty = traj[i,1] - centerline[idx, 1]

        # unrotate the trajectory point by the angle of the line segment to get to (s,d) coordinates
        sd[i, 0] = (bx*tx + by*ty) + dists[idx]
        sd[i, 1] = (by*tx - bx*ty)

    return sd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for making that clear!
Also thanks for the alternative ideas - it works like a charm.